# Hidden copying constructor C++

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I would like to create class which can't be copied, so I put copying constructor into the private section:

```
class NotCopyable
{
public:
    NotCopyable(const double& attr1, const double& attr2) : _attr1(attr1), _attr2(attr2) {}
    ~NotCopyable(void) {}

private:
    NotCopyable& operator=(const NotCopyable&);
    NotCopyable(const NotCopyable&);
    double _attr1;
    double _attr2;
};
```

Everything is OK except when I would like to assign the array:

```
NotCopyable arr[] =
{
    NotCopyable(1, 0),
    NotCopyable(2, 3)
};
```

The compiler says that she can't access copying constructor as it is in private section.
When I put it in public section:

```
class NotCopyable
{
public:
    NotCopyable(const double& attr1, const double& attr2) : _attr1(attr1), _attr2(attr2) {}
    ~NotCopyable(void) {}
    NotCopyable(const NotCopyable&)
    {
        std::cout << "COPYING" << std:: endl;
    }
private:
    NotCopyable& operator=(const NotCopyable&);

    double _attr1;
    double _attr2;
};
```

Program compiles without errors, but copying constructor isn't called. So the question is: how do I forbid copying but still have possibility to assign arrays?

Comment: Impossible. "assigning" arrays is still "assignment", which you're trying to forbid

Comment: You can't assign to arrays. The code shown here is *initializing* an array, which, even if it uses the same symbol, is not assignment.

Comment: You may want to read this: http://physical-thought.blogspot.com/2008/08/noncopyable-c-class-which-cannot-be.html esp the second comment written by the author as to when you want to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code `arr [] = { NotCopyable(1,2) };` does request the copy constructor, at least formally. Practically the copy is usually elided, but that falls under the "as-if" rule, and the copy constructor still has to be accessible, even though ultimately it isn't used. (In GCC you can say `-fno-elide-constructors` to actually invoke the copy constructor.)

You can't solve this in C++03, where brace-initialization always necessitates a formal copy. In C++11 you can use brace initialization to direct-initialize array members, though:

```
NotCopyable arr[] { {1, 0}, {2, 3} };
```

This works even in the absence of an accessible copy constructor.

Comment: This isn't the "as-if" rule, as that would require the output of "COPYING".  This is the exception in 12.8/15 of the Standard, which essentially extends the "as-if" rule so the copy constructor need not be called when copying a temporary object (even if, as in this case, there are side effects in the copy constructor.

Comment: @DavidThornley: I know, I was being a bit cavalier about that. Indeed, it is legal to elide the copy constructor *even if* it has side effects. What I meant was sort of a reverse "as-if" rule, in so far as both copy initialization and direct-initialization-through-copy-constructor imply semantics "as if" the copy constructor were to be called (and copy elision only kicks in later during optimization).

Answer (score 1):

It is incorrect, because you use array of objects that have to be created by copying:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class NotCopyable
{
public:
    NotCopyable(const double& attr1, const double& attr2) : _attr1(attr1), _attr2(attr2) {}
    ~NotCopyable(void) {}

private:
    NotCopyable& operator=(const NotCopyable&);
    NotCopyable(const NotCopyable&);
    double _attr1;
    double _attr2;
};

int main()
{
    vector<NotCopyable> v;
    NotCopyable a(1, 2);
    v.push_back(a); // THIS IS COPYING
    return 0;
}
```

Since you have disabled copying, you can store reference only. You should make it array of **pointers**:

```
NotCopyable a(1, 2);

// incorrect:
vector<NotCopyable> v;
v.push_back(a);

// correct:
vector<NotCopyable*> v2;
v2.push_back(&a);
```

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
NotCopyable arr[] =
{
    NotCopyable(1, 0),
    NotCopyable(2, 3)
};
```

When you write this, the compiler needs copy-constructor, as it is *copy-initialization*. That is why you get compilation error, as the copy-constructor is declared `private`, and so it is inaccessible from outside. However, if you define it in the `public` section, then it works, but copy-constructor is not getting called, which is because of the optimization done by the compiler. The specification allows the compiler to elide the invocation of the copy-constructor in such situation, however it still needs *accessible* copy-constructor only for semantic-check of the code. It isn't actually called once the semantic check is done!

Comment: But how to allow using constructor for initialization but forbid using in other cases?

Comment: Is it copy-initialization or direct-initialization using the copy-constructor? I.e. is `T arr[] = { T(1), T(2) };` interpreted like `T arr1(T(1)), arr2(T(2));` or like `T arr1 = T(1), arr2 = T(2);`?

Comment: @KerrekSB: I think its copy-initilization. But that seems irrelevant here, because either way, the copy-constructor is needed for semantic check.